# Determine Number of Simplex Iterations

Tags: optimization, simplex

I have an assignment, which asks me to determine the least number of simplex iterations necessary to solve different optimization problems.  One problem is: a model with 1150 constraints and 2340 variables.  I want to say that the least number of iterations is equal to either the number of constraints or the number of variables, but I'm really not sure.  A hint as to how I could go about solving this problem would be greatly appreciated, if I understand this example, then I am confident that I'll be able to solve the other problems as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of simplex as walking around the edges of the feasible set until it gets to the vertex, which represents the optimal solution.

- What is the initial basis?
- What is the final basis that yields the optimal solution?

Each iteration alters one variable, how many do you have to drop and how many do you have to add?